# Why need Develop Branch in GitFlow

Tags: git

We know git-flow like this
[image]
*Source: [Vincent Driessen](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)*

I don't know why we need the develop branch. What problems will cause without a develop branch? Why not merge feature branches to release branches directly?

Comment: (building on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52594075/10278 answer by @user6645697 ...) the original Driessen post on GitFlow now contains a semi-retraction at the top, labeled "Note of Reflection, March 5, 2020"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can not release everytime you develop a new feature, you make a release when the the develop branch is in a 'releasable' state. i.e the end user can accualy use that version. So the master branch reflects releases and hot fixes whcih can be used by the end user. in other words, the master head is always a release which can be used, you can not get that without the develop branch.

Vincent Driessen wrote:

> We consider origin/master to be the main branch where the source code
>   of HEAD always reflects a production-ready state.
>
> We consider origin/develop to be the main branch where the source code
>   of HEAD always reflects a state with the latest delivered development
>   changes for the next release. Some would call this the “integration
>   branch”. This is where any automatic nightly builds are built from.

you can get all of the original post [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I wouldn't say that the given answer properly explains, why the develop branch and the master branch are both needed to achieve a releasable state. The version tags created on each release also reflect the releasable state and in Git you can always create a new branch based on these tags subsequently if needed.

In fact, there are multiple blog posts that criticize the Git Flow model and propose a more convenient branching model, which only uses one main branch, i. e. the "master". Here are the references:

https://reallifeprogramming.com/git-process-that-works-say-no-to-gitflow-50bf2038ccf7
https://www.endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful

Thus, the actual answer to this question should be: You don't necessarily need the develop branch if you adapt your workflow as described in the linked posts. Still, you wouldn't merge your features into the release branches, but to the master branch, as you want them to be available in the future versions as well.